# Cannot build backup WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I needed an update for my project, so before update process I make a backup from my project(make a rar from project folder).

Before backup I could build it correctly.
Now I want to use my backup, I extract my rar file as new folder.
When I want to build it there is an error :

```
MC1000  Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SuppressIldasmAttribute' in assembly 
'C:\Users\Admin\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.1\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Runtime.dll'.'    
StoreManager    C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets 240
```

I use WPF .net core 3.1 and I tried this solution :

Clean solution and rebuild.

delete .VS - bin - obj and rebuild.

update packeges

[image]

Comment: Check to make sure you have a valid reference to `System.Runtime.dll` in your project.  That said, this isn't a particularly useful attribute; all it does is prevent someone from using ILDASM.EXE on your project, but there are other programs like Telerik JustDecompile that can disassemble your code regardless of this attribute's presence.

Comment: I disassemble unnecessary component It didn't work. before Backup I could build with these assemblies